# Why/when do I need a 'clean' target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Sometimes it seems like not a new executable is built, even though I need one, but I don't understand why. For example, when I change a Makefile, but there is already an executable, and when I execute 'make' it doesn't create an updated executable.

Isn't the whole purpose of Makefiles so that I don't need to worry about that stuff anymore?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [GNU make documentation](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/make/make.html)

> The recompilation must be done if the source file, or any of the header files named as dependencies, is more recent than the object file, or if the object file does not exist.

It's not changing your Makefile that triggers it.

`make clean` removes all the object files that had been created in the meantime. *Normally*, it's no big deal to partially recompile, i.e. only to recompile the files you changed and finally link the newly created object files with the pre-existing ones. Still, if you want to be absolutely safe, you should run `make clean` before running `make` again.

An example where keeping old object files (i.e. never running make clean) may become a problem: Suppose you have an already existing object file that is meant to be linked against version 1.0 of some library. Now you update your machine and this will install version 1.1 on it, where some function is incompatible to the of function 1.0. But since your object file was compiled expecting the prior version the linking process will ultimately fail.

Comment: I'm not convinced by your example. If an update to a library changes its interface, then you will have to make changes to your code anyway, which would cause a recompilation of the affected objects. So no need for `make clean` there.

Comment: Not necessarily - if the rest of your files you are working on will not rely on that specific library, the affected objects would not be recompiled.

Comment: If any objects are incompatible with the new library, their source should be changed anyway to reflect the changes in interface. Doing a `make clean` won't make that go away, and linking will still fail.

Comment: Nope, but the compiler will complain that something is messed up. It's much harder to detect than without `make clean`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a very broad question. Generally, you can write a makefile which will track all the dependencies (including it's own modification time). However it's non trivial and bugs can crawl to your makefile the same as to any other code. So, sometimes it's easier to clean everything and rebuild when suspecting that something was not built correctly.

There are many [other build tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software), such as [scons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCons) which might be more robust/automatic than makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Make analyzies the depedencies defined in your Makefiles and build a dependency graph out of that.

If it detects that any of the prequisites need by the output (binaries) changes it is rebuild - or at least the part that has changed.

So, if your dependency includes the Makefiles - it probably shouldn't - make would update the binary once you change the Makefile.

Life with Makefiles doesn't always easier but it can help you very much anyway.